# Regex failing to exclude matches with line break

Tags: python, regex

I run the following regex. I am breaking it down using variables for greater clarity:

```
all_no_numb_newline = r'(?:[^\n\d]*\n)' ## I include an extra line just to get more context ##
all_no_numb = r'(?:[^\n\d]*)' ## I do not want there to be any numbers on the same line except the ID ##
x1 = r'(?!(1-888-555|\(888\)))' ## I am excluding a specific common phone number ##
x2 = r'(?![\n\/])\W{0,2}' ## I am excluding line breaks and date formats ##
id_re = f'({x1}\d(?:{x2}\d){{16}}\d)' ## This is an ID number 18 digits long with some symbols in between ##
```

Basically, I am trying to identify an ID that is 18 digits long. **I don't want to match 18 digits that include any letters, line breaks, or forward slashes. If I match an 18 digit ID with other random symbols, that is fine.** I also don't want to match to an ID preceded by any numbers. I also want to match to an extra line before the main group to give me better context about my match, however I am really after the id_re match (this is why I put a question mark "?" next to the all_nno_numb_new_line).

Then I run the following code using:

```
re.findall(
    "("+
    all_no_numb_newline+"?"+
    all_no_numb+
    id_re+")"
    , text)[0]
```

However, this is still returning the following match:

```
('L1 (061510)\n1009671-1000', '1 (061510)\n1009671-1000', '')
```

I expected there to be no line breaks and I expected there to be two groups (my general match and my ID group). Why are there 3 groups instead of 2? And why does "\n", ie a line break, appear in the match?

**EDIT: EXAMPLES OF MATCHES**

```
'Mortgage\nID 756953480812037780'
')\n*DT756953480812037780'
'\nq75695348081 0233 240'
')\n*DT756953480812037780'
'\nq03313375233 0233 329'
'ID 676170114397739293'
'ID NUMBER 676170114397739293'
'ID\n676170114397739293'
'ID676170114397739293'

OUTPUT:

'756953480812037780'
'756953480812037780'
'75695348081 0233 240'
'756953480812037780'
'03313375233 0233 329'
'676170114397739293'
'676170114397739293'
'676170114397739293'
'676170114397739293'
```

**EDIT: EXAMPLES THAT SHOULD NOT MATCH**

```
'L1 (061510)\n1009671-1000'
'L1 081510)\n1009671-1000'
'L1 (061510)\n1009671-1000'
```

Comment: If you could add some input to test and explain what exact result you want to achieve - this could help to debug this.

Comment: Ok will do, let me throw in some results

Comment: What does "*I don't want to match 18 digits that include any letters, line breaks, or forward slashes. If I match an 18 digit ID with other random symbols, that is fine.*" mean? Why is your expression like you wrote?

Comment: It means that 

'L1 (061510)\n1009671-1000' or 
'L1 081510)\n1009671-1000' or
'L1 (061510)\n1009671-1000'


should not be matched my the regex engine because it has a line break in it

Comment: Kindly excuse my dumbness, but could you please give result examples corresponding the input example you given? From the set of strings in your example what lines should match and what should not?

Comment: Try the regex from the answer below, just use word boundaries, `r'\b(?!(?:1-888-555|\(888\)))(\d(?:\W{0,2}\d){16}\d)\b'`

Comment: everything under "Examples of matches" include input and output for the lines that should match. everything under examples that should not match include input for lines that should not match. currently, my regex is matching to both sets of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
(?<!\d)\d(?:\s*\d){16}\d(?!\d)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/V0WcqL/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (16 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){16}                    end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear--I'm not trying to remove, I'm trying to exclude matches with a line break

Comment: @econfin That is not clearer. Explain all in the question.

Comment: Just added the following in bold:
I don't want to match 18 digits that include any letters, line breaks, or forward slashes. If I match an 18 digit ID with other random symbols, that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ryszard's answer eliminated \n. I went about it a more hackey way:

```
                YY = r'(?!-888-)'
                XX = r'[^A-Za-z\d\n\\\/\)\(]{0,2}'
                id_re= f'({YY}\d(?:{XX}\d|\d{XX}){{16}}\d)'
```

YY eliminates a common phone number from showing up
XX keep all non-alphanumeric characters excluding \n. Other procedures kept showing up with \n no matter how many lookaheads/behinds I implemented. So I decided to using a simpler but more hack of a route by hand-eliminating all alphanumeric and \n (along with extra symbols that would confuse dates or phone numbers with slashes and parentheses).

This regex was so successful that I got almost a 99% match!